# react-router location did not match any routes during first load page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I saw a lot of solutions, but nothing helped me. I am still getting error `Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes` my code `index.js` -

```
import { Router, Route, Redirect, browserHistory } from 'react-router'; 
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory} >{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById("app"));

    module.exports = (
        <Route path="/" handler={App}>
            {console.log(Pages["Graph"])}
            <Redirect from="/" to="/graph"/>
            <Route path="/graph" handler={Pages["Graph"]}/>
        </Route>
    );
```

then in `App.js` -

```
return (
            <div className="App-Master">
                <Header data={this.state.data.header} />
                <Navigation data={this.state.data.menu} switchLanguage={this.switchLanguage.bind(this)} />
                <div className="content">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
```

I have no links yet. This error i am getting during first loading page..

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-router": "^2.6.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there're a few things going wrong here to me. Let's split up your routes into a dedicated Routes.js file. As your app grows you'll want to keep it separate anyway. Export it like so, and make sure you're importing the components you want the routes to point to. I think you're running into issues with the way you're exporting and rendering the routes to the dom.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from './filepath/app.js';

export default (
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
           <IndexRoute component={App} />
             //other stuff
        </Route>
)
```

Then you want to import the routes into your index.js file, and wire up the DOM:

```
import { Router, Route, Redirect, browserHistory } from 'react-router'; 
import routes from './filepath/routes';

ReactDOM.render(
     <Router
        history={browserHistory}
        routes={routes}
     />, document.querySelector('#app'));
);
```

[This tutorial](http://davidmeents.com/journey-into-react-part-3-navigating-between-webpages-with-react-router/) might help too. Disclaimer - I wrote it!

Hopefully this, or the tutorial helps! Happy coding!

Comment: Ehm. can i replace component with handler? I am trying to make project from another simillar and it has got a handler...

Comment: I don't think so, I have not seen any official docs or examples concerning using `handler` instead of `component`. I've always used the `component` method.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

Comment: https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/react-router-an-introduction/ there is one solution with handler, and i don't understand the difference between these two.. I reader somewhere that handler allow dynamic routes... dont know what is mean :D so i hope your solution will be enough :))

Comment: Yeah, I was actually reading that one too, strange I've not heard of it until then. Best of luck, I hope it works as well. Let me know!

Comment: I just read comment in link above, and he said that Handler and DefaultRoute and so on, are syntax of older version react-router... so i hope thats all, and there is no different... so i will do it in your solution... thanks a lot :))